# Split DataFrame into groups that contain only a given constant value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame that I want to split into multiple groups. Each group will be a sequence of rows where the column `difference` is equal to 1. If not, skip it and find the next row with `difference` equal to 1 and start a new group.

For example this:

```
    id  difference
0   001 1
1   001 1
2   001 1
3   001 1
4   001 1
5   001 1
6   001 2
7   001 2
8   001 1
9   001 1
10  001 1
11  001 1
12  001 4
13  001 1
14  001 1
15  001 1
16  001 1
17  001 1
18  001 1
19  001 1
```

will be 3 dfs first: from 0 to 5 (including 5), second: from 8 to 11, and third: from 13 to 19

Right now I do it this way, and I am new to pandas. Is there any other efficient way of doing it?

```
grouped = g.df((g['difference'] != g['difference'].shift()).cumsum())
for group_id, group in grouped:
    if (group['difference'].iloc[0] < 1.1) & (group['difference'].iloc[0] > 0.9) and len(
            group.index) > 1:
        #do stuff...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your splitting `condition`, use [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to create pseudo-groups for [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). Then use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to ignore rows that violate the `condition` and extract the groups in a dict comprehension:

```
condition = df.difference != 1
dfs = {key: data for key, data in df.loc[~condition].groupby(condition.cumsum())}
```

Note that if you want to include `id` as a splitting condition, just add it to the [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and unpack accordingly:

```
dfs = {key: data for (_, key), data in df.loc[~condition].groupby(['id', condition.cumsum()])}
#                    ^^^^^^^^                                      ^^^^
```

Output:

```
{0:
      id  difference
 0   001           1
 1   001           1
 2   001           1
 3   001           1
 4   001           1
 5   001           1,

 2:
      id  difference
 8   001           1
 9   001           1
 10  001           1
 11  001           1,

 3:
      id  difference
 13  001           1
 14  001           1
 15  001           1
 16  001           1
 17  001           1
 18  001           1
 19  001           1}
```

Comment: Related: [How to detect sequences of 3 nulls + 1 non-null in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70223106/13138364)